# Regex pattern match with an optional ending comma

Tags: java, regex, string

```
 Input String : "slack,users@xyz.com , slack,auditors@xyz.com , abc@xyz.com"
```

Regex I am using :

```
(.+?)@(.+?),
```

Current Output :

```
Group 0 - slack,users@xyz.com ,
Group 1 - slack,auditors@xyz.com ,
```

The output I want :

```
Group 0 - slack,users@xyz.com
Group 1 - slack,auditors@xyz.com
Group 2 - abc@xyz.com
```

My Code :

```
    String regex = "(.+?)@(.+?),";       
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher m =pattern.matcher("slack,users@xyz.com , slack,auditors@xyz.com , abc@xyz.com");


    while(m.find()){
       System.out.println(m.group());
    }
```

How do I modify my regex so that it will make the ending comma optional so that the last group in the form of "user@domain" is also matched?

Also, how can i split the string in some way so that the ending comma is not part of the resulting groups?

Comment: Instead of `,`, use `(?:,|$)`.

Comment: Or better, `([^,]+)` instead of `(.+?),`

Comment: This could be underkill, but if your input is always the same format, why not split on ` , ` (space, comma, space) ?

Comment: This seems to work:

`(?:\w*,|)\w*@\w*\.\w*`

Let's have a look at the parts, with the first element of your list:

- `(?:\w*,|)` non-capturing group that will look the `slack,` element
- `\w*` looks for a word/number/underscore, n times, like the `user` element
- `@` is literal
- `\w*` looks for another word/number/underscore, n times, like the `xyz` element
- `\.` will match a literal `.`
- `\w*` again to match the domain name